# Pull latest record from multiple condition case expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, sql-order-by, case

I'm dealing with a situation where I need to pull only one record for a patient based on a specific diagnosis. In this instance, a patient can have multiple diagnoses, which are listed as `current_icd10_list`, and each diagnosis is done on a visit, which can be discerned by the contact date. In this case, a patient can be diagnosed with multiple diagnoses of similar types at different times, but I only need to pull the latest one. In my example, let's say I had a patient who was diagnosed with `Dx 1` first and then `Dx 2 at` a later date. I only want to pull the latest diagnosis, which would be `Dx 2`. How would I do this?

```
select 
CONTACT_DATE,                
WHEN current_icd10_list LIKE '%E10.0%'
...
OR current_icd10_list LIKE '%E14.9%' 
THEN 'Dx 1'

WHEN current_icd10_list LIKE '%E10.2%'
...
OR current_icd10_list LIKE '%E14.7%' 
THEN 'Dx 2'
END AS 'Dx Group'
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pull only one record for a patient based on a specific diagnosis [...] A patient can have multiple diagnoses [...] but I only need to pull the latest one.

You would use `row_number()` for this. Assuming that the id of the patient is stored in column `patient_id` and that the date of the visit is stored in `contact_date`:

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by patient_id order by contact_date desc) rn
    from mytable t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you not be able to just pull using the max date function using your criteria of the current_icd10_list? For instance:

```
select max(CONTACT_DATE) as max_date,                
case WHEN current_icd10_list LIKE '%E10.0%'
OR current_icd10_list LIKE '%E14.9%' 
THEN 'Dx 1'

WHEN current_icd10_list LIKE '%E10.2%'
OR current_icd10_list LIKE '%E14.7%' 
THEN 'Dx 2'
END AS 'Dx Group'

from mytable 

group by 
case WHEN current_icd10_list LIKE '%E10.0%'
OR current_icd10_list LIKE '%E14.9%' 
THEN 'Dx 1'

WHEN current_icd10_list LIKE '%E10.2%'
OR current_icd10_list LIKE '%E14.7%' 
THEN 'Dx 2'
END
 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this by separating the patients that had a Dx in 'Dx group' and used row_number to order them by contact_date. I then union'd it back to the rest of the data.